# og membership role is not displayed in views

Tags: views, organic-groups

I'm using organic group module and I have 3 og membership types:

- 'member'
- 'non-member'
- 'visitor'.

I created an view which shows me all user group listing under one group which includes users role also but it is not displayed.

In view I added an Relationships as 'OG membership: OG membership from User ' and added filed for the same.

Answer (score 2):

To work with user-roles in a view, you also need the relationship "OG membership: OG Roles from membership", where you have to set the relationship to your previously added "OG membership from user"-relation.

After that you are able to display the user's role or filter by user-roles. Hopefully this information was helpful for you.

Comment: same problem..! unable to display even I followed above instructions